# How to stop List and ScrollView from changing TabView Bar

Tags: ios, swiftui, uiscrollview, tabview

In my MainView I have a TabView, when my ListView is selected and I start scrolling, it makes my TabView turn solid Black/White. Is there a way to stop this from happening. with my other View I had a similar problem and putting it in a VStack solved it. But that does not work. I can't find anyway to stop the auto tinting

I also don't want the top bar that tints when scrolling in a NavigationStack. How can this be adjusted?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for anyone else trying to find it with my apparent bad description

```
init() {

let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
tabBarAppearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
tabBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .clear
tabBarAppearance.backgroundEffect = nil
tabBarAppearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
tabBarAppearance.backgroundImage = UIImage()

UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance
UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance

}
```

Comment: then adding this "init() {
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()

        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    }" to the destination view removes the bar at the top